# Need comment about my WordPress solution to show sticky post in home (with category link as title instead of post link)

Tags: wordpress

I thinks I should share share this solutions  with all..

I am adding a solution for showing only sticky posts in index.php and the link to go to category page(not post page) with The Loop and adding classes dynamically to the posts so that its easy to write css for them.

Add the code in index.

```
<div class="home col-xs-12" >

                    <?php
                while(have_posts()) {
                    the_post();
                    if ( is_sticky()) { 
                        $postid = get_the_ID();
                         global $post;
                         $post_slug=$post->post_name; 
                        ?>

                    <div  id="<?php echo $postid.'csscid'.$post_slug?>" class="content-block col-xs-12">                          
                      <h1 ><?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></h1> 

                        <hr class="color-strip">
                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 11); ?></p>
                        <div class="tags"><ul><li><?php the_tags(); ?></li></ul></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
            <?php }
        }?>


</div>
```

Comment: And what is the question / problem?

Comment: Question is not clear?

Comment: I said in the question .I need comment on my code. Is it a standard practice?